# How to use MOSFET as a switch to drive LEDs

Tags: led, mosfet, driver

LEDs used : 150 mA, Vf = 3.1 V

I need to control 3 LEDS using a microcontroller signal with MOSFET acting as a switch. I am having trouble selecting the MOSFET and deriving the gate current.

The MOSFET I have currently is IRF540N, Vdd = 5 V, I need to find out the values of resistance between LED and source, and R in gate.

Comment: What have you tried so far, and what problems have you run into? See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: IRF540 is not an appropriate mosfet. You need a logic level mosfet. Try find an IRL** mosfet

Comment: What PWM frequency are you using? What is "R-gate"?

Answer (score 2):

The MOSFET gate current will be zero, unless you have a broken FET.

Choose a logic level drive FET. These are specified to be well on with 5v or less on the gate. Most 'normal level' FETs will be sort of on by 5v, but their resistance is only specified at 10v gate drive.

At 150mA, almost any FET will do, including the SOT23 sizes. But check in the data sheet for the drain current just to make sure.

Comment: Drain current should be greater than 450mA? Since I am using 3 LEDs in series.

Comment: if the LEDs are in series, the current will be 150mA, and you'll need >10v supply for them. If they're in parallel, you'll need 450mA, and a >4v supply. What are you going to do to control the current in the LEDs?